# Java networkinterface.isVirtual() method Always return value is false?

Tags: java

Under what circumstances the return value is true??

thank you all!

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterface = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (networkInterface.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface eachNetworkInterface = networkInterface
                        .nextElement();
                System.out.println(eachNetworkInterface.getName() + " "
                        + eachNetworkInterface.isVirtual());
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

print result all false!!!
why??how do print true?

Comment: If network interface found it will print the interface name and a space " " and whether it is virtual or now(which might be true or false)..

Comment: how do can print value is true?

Answer (score 3):

According to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isVirtual--):

> Returns whether this interface is a virtual interface (also called
>   subinterface). Virtual interfaces are, on some systems, interfaces
>   created as a child of a physical interface and given different
>   settings (like address or MTU). Usually the name of the interface will
>   the name of the parent followed by a colon (:) and a number
>   identifying the child since there can be several virtual interfaces
>   attached to a single physical interface.

If you get all `false`, that just means there are no subinterfaces created in your system.

Comment: Amila how do create subinterfaces??next  let me print value is true,thank you !

Comment: In Windows, you can install "Microsoft Loopback Adapter" using add hardware wizard.

Comment: Amila,i installed "loopback adapter",but print result is false too.

Comment: lo Software Loopback Interface 1 false
eth9 Microsoft Loopback Adapter false
eth10 Microsoft Loopback Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000 false
eth11 Microsoft Loopback Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000 false

Comment: @Gaohongyan my mistake, there is a separate method to check isLoopback(). Apparently loopback interface doesn't fall into the category of subinterfaces.

Comment: Hello Amila!!Linux operate system value is true!!!windows not!!!thank you very much !

Comment: In the Linux operating system create subinterface